# Virtual Host and .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, virtualhost

I am facing very different issue for past few days. My website is working some time and not working some time in (UAE). But it was perfectly working in india.  Here with i have specified the virtual host setup and .htaccess.

```
<VirtualHost ip:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@basetestserver.com
    DocumentRoot /path/
    ServerName www.oneearthproperties.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost ip:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@basetestserver.com
    DocumentRoot /path/
    ServerName oneearthproperties.com
</VirtualHost>
```

My .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Did any one faced this type of difficulties before?

Comment: Show the real contents of your virtual host setup.

Comment: and the appropriate parts of the server logs.

Comment: `^system.*` seems never matches, as it's without forward slash

Comment: And also what do you mean by not working? What else its displaying than any errors?

Comment: @Deadooshka Doesn't make sense! If it never matches it will skip to the next condition.

Comment: @RahilWazir That is my real virtual host setup in apache. ip address would by my server ip address. When i ping www.oneearthproperties.com in india it was working fine. I can see my ip address. When i ping in uae it shows could not find the host.

Comment: Have you contacted to your hosting provider? This information is not enough as @OliveMatthews said provide us your server error logs.

Comment: When i used tracert -d www.oneearthproperties.com it says unable to resolve target system name.